# (Due to the Chrome 53 issue)Yahoo weather api got an insecure certificare which failed the jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl, yahoo-weather-api

I have been using Yahoo weather api to get weather info for one year. I am using

[https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places(1) WHERE text='(31.020780,121.454648)') and u='c' &format=json](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(SELECT%20woeid%20FROM%20geo.places(1)%20WHERE%20text='(31.020780,121.454648)')%20and%20u='c'%20&format=json)

and it was working fine.

Recently I began to get "net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE" error in ajax call and get "Your connection is not private" warning when I accessed it thru browsers. It seems that there is no chance the ajax client can programmatically trust the ssl certificate.

Is there anyone have the same problem with me? How to workaround this in JavaScript?

Thanks everyone for the answer.
It proves to be a browser issue. https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/4158 Google chrome version 53 has the problem.

Comment: isnt this a browser issue?

Comment: which browser it occurred?

Comment: I am using chrome.

Comment: I do not see an issue with query.yahooapis.com's certificate for it not to be trusted. My Chrome browser opens the link you've posted without any error --https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=query.yahooapis.com. Do you have something installed (antivirus perhaps) that may be intercepting your HTTPS connections?

Comment: @AnandBhat I have to click "Advanced" to proceed with the request. Didn't you have the problem?

Comment: No, the link opens up just fine. Can you post a screenprint of the certificate that you see for query.yahooapis.com?

Comment: @AnandBhat thanks for the reminding. The problem is due to the chrome version 53's issue. I will upgrade it to a newer version.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for updating your question. Chrome 54 is out and I can confirm it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

http://weather.yahooapis.com/

to

http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/

If the above is not working. Head in [here](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/04/15/example-yahoo-weather-yql-to-fetch-forecasts-and-render-with-jquery/). And replicate [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ikromin/misc/master/yahooweather/weather_yql_example.html) and save as `.html` file and view it in your browser.

Additionaly, try to change query to this:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='(31.020780,121.454648)') and u='c'
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: just try it and let me know if it isn't fix

Comment: I replaced "https://query.yahooapis.com" with "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/" but got network error. Seems that the link is not valid.

Comment: But my problem is insecure ssl certificate. I don't think it would work cos they are still using the same url "https://query.yahooapis.com". And there is no problem with the YQL. It was just blocked by the SSL cert verification.

Comment: If not can you post the error in your console? @Theresa